# ¿Cómo cambiar el tamaño de video en CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, html-video

estoy intentado colocar un vídeo, estoy utilizando HTML y CSS, el vídeo lo intento colocar en un cierto tamaño, pero me abarca toda la pantalla, desconozco si se cambia el tamaño diferente a como se lo coloco a una imagen, espero me puedan apoyar. Intento colocar el vídeo de lado izquiero y mi texto `Hola Mundo` a la derecha

Código HTML:

```
<div class=a>
        <div class="imagen_iso_uno">
            <!--<img class="img_iso1" src="img/iso1.jpg" alt="imagen">-->
            <video onloadstart="this.muted=true" autoplay loop>
                <source src="videos/prueba.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="texto_iso ">
            <div class="raya_2">
                <h1>HOLA MUNDO :)</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Código CSS

```
.imagen_iso_uno video {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: seagreen;
    border-radius: 3rem;
}

.texto_iso {
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucedía era que el texto tenía desmasiado ancho. Entonces, al no poder ir a la derecha conservando todo el ancho que le otorgaste, se iba para abajo. Aquí te dejo como solucionarlo:

```css
.imagen_iso_uno video {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: seagreen;
    border-radius: 3rem;
}

.raya_2{
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class=a>
        <div class="imagen_iso_uno">
            <!--<img class="img_iso1" src="img/iso1.jpg" alt="imagen">-->
            <video onloadstart="this.muted=true" autoplay loop>
                <source src="videos/prueba.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
            <div class="raya_2">
                <h1>HOLA MUNDO :)</h1>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :) me ha funcionado

Comment: Me alegra que te sirva :)